# SelectList throwing "Object reference not set" error even after initializing in Constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have below `Model`

```
public class UploadImageAlbum
{
    public UploadImageAlbum()
    {
       Albums = new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>());
    }
    public List<HttpPostedFileBase> Images { get; set; }

    public string AlbumID { get; set; }
    public SelectList Albums { get; set; }
}

public class Album
{
   public string AlbumID { get; set; }
   public string AlbumName { get; set; }
}

public class Repository
{
   public static List<Album> FetchAlbums()
   {
        List<Album> albums = new List<Album>
        {
            new Album(){ AlbumID = "Album1", AlbumName = "Album 1 desc"},
            new Album(){ AlbumID = "Album2", AlbumName = "Album 2 desc"}
        };
        return albums;
    }
}
```

and I call this `UploadImageAlbum` in a separate model called `AdminViewModel` as below:

```
public class AdminViewModel
{
    public UploadImageAlbum UIAModel { get; set; }
}
```

and in `Controller` I try to fill this `model` as below:

```
public PartialViewResult GetMediaUploadView()
{
   AdminViewModel model = new AdminViewModel();
   List<Album> albums = Repository.FetchAlbums();
   model.UIAModel.Albums = new SelectList(albums, "AlbumID", "AlbumName");//Error here
   //Object reference not set to an instance of the object
   return PartialView("_UploadMedia", model);
}
```

I also tried

```
public PartialViewResult GetMediaUploadView()
{
   AdminViewModel model = new AdminViewModel();
        List<Album> albums = new List<Album>(); //Creating as new List
        albums = Repository.FetchAlbums();//then assign
        model.UIAModel.Albums = new SelectList(albums, "AlbumID", "AlbumName");
        return PartialView("_UploadMedia", model);
}
```

But again, I am getting same error. No idea for what reason I am getting this error, even after initializing in model level as well as Controller level. Hope someone might have good knowledge on this. Below is the screen shot of the error I am getting.

[image: Screenshot]

**Update**

Well I don't think this is the duplicate, as I am too aware that there are 'n' number of questions based on `null reference`, But the level where we get that `null reference` is what makes this question unique. Also I was in impression that, the `SelectList` was throwing error, turned out the problem to be different here. So I stand by with my question

Comment: Looks like `model.UIAModel` is `null`

Comment: `model.UIAModel` looks `null` to me. so `model.UIAModel.Albums` is the real error thrower here. try create an object in constructor of `AdminViewModel` for `UIAModel`.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Well people often think seeing the title, but if you read the question, then you wouldn't have though so.. :) The Solution might be general, **Something is null and not initialized**, but which hierarchy it comes up to be `null` is what makes question unique.. :) Anyways, I stand by my point and hope this helps someone in future.. :) Happy coding.. :)

Comment: @GuruprasadRao The duplicate is about how to determine exactly what is `null` which was your main issue.  If you had known that it was `model.UIAModel` and not just `model` then the solutions should have been more obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `AdminViewModel` has a property:

```
public class AdminViewModel
{
    public UploadImageAlbum UIAModel { get; set; }
}
```

then:

```
AdminViewModel model = new AdminViewModel();
//..
model.UIAModel.Albums = //...
```

you haven't initialized `UIAModel`, he's throwing the error.

---

If you're in `C#6` you can simply use:

```
public class AdminViewModel
{
    public UploadImageAlbum UIAModel { get; set; } = new UploadImageAlbum();
}
```

for a quick fix

Comment: No, I am not using C#6, So I can have this in `AdminViewModel` Constructor too right?

Comment: yes, you can do it in your ctor, just like you intialized `Albums` in your `UploadImageAlbum` ctor

Comment: Superb. Thanks for the help bro.. Happy Coding.. :)